# Trigger alert if email isn't received every n hours

Tags: email, automation, alert

I'm looking for a way to get alerted when I don't receive a certain email in time.

The situation is as follows:

I have a Synology NAS that takes hourly backups of my files. Upon completing the backup job the NAS sends an email to an address that I configured. The backup jobs usually take a few minutes so that the email is sent a few minutes after a full hour.

I'd like to set something up (email inbox rules, ifttt, insert more cloud services...) to notify me if the that report email isn't received in a timely manner or contains an error message.

I've already had a look at ifttt but that doesn't seem to cover this sort of approach. I can pick the email provider of the target email address freely so.

Any ideas what to do here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thought I have on this I wanted to run by you just in case you find it helpful. . . Are you able to tell it to only send the email if the backup job fails or runs into an error, etc. I find it easier to manager to only be notified if an error or failure occurs and that's your indicator that action is needed. It's too easy to over look an email when you receive one every hour so that approach works better for the hundreds of jobs I support and maintain. If you need something indicating that this system is up, maybe one every 6 or 12 hours saying the Synology NAS is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

In the Synology system settings under Notifications > Advanced success messages for backups can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a tool called SMTPViewer.com that does exactly what you are asking.

The system informs you when for example the word "failed" is in the subject or in the content of your mail. It will also address the isue of not receiving any e-mail with a handy time out feature which warns you when no e-mails has been received for a set time. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sure there are many software recommendations that can be made that does this same thing too.